# Dual Displays overlap on startup?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, screen

Heyo, got a slight problem here. Whenever I start up my Ubuntu 14.04, my displays decide to overlap each other, not unlike [this](http://gyazo.com/16ff5c0461219cb3e96015d1a4a89b6b). An easy fix is to go to the display settings and drag the small screen away from the inside of the big screen, but it gets annoying. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the monitors config file or edit it, but deleting it is the easier choice and should hopefully solve your problem:

```
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: fixed it for me

Comment: still valid in linux mint 18.2

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice program called `arandr`. It allows saving current layout as a shell script. So edit the layout as you need, save the shell script, make it executable with `chmod 755 /path/to/script.sh`. Now you can add that as one of the autostart entries in `Startup Applications`, so on every GUI log-in your configuration will be reset